# Question regarding libraries and framework

Tags: c++

Sorry i'm a beginner,from what i know there are number of varieties of libraries and framework out there provided for the C++ language.My question is,when we create an application using the framework and libraries,do the users of the application need to install the framework or so so call the libraries on his/her PC??Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether the library you are using is statically or dynamically linked. In the former case, it is part of the executable file that you distribute. In the latter case, it is an extra file (or set of files) with extensions such as .so or .dll, which you should distribute with your app.

Answer (score 0):

The end-user need to have the framework installed.

As you need to have .Net installed to run some Microsoft(and other companies) products. If your application is written in C++ using [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). You need to have they installed, but if you're on Linux using [KDE](http://www.kde.org/), Qt is natively installed for default, the same for [Gnome](http://www.gnome.org/) and also the same of Cocoa on Mac and Cocoa-Touch on iPhone and iPod Touch.

I suggest you to have the installer of the framework used embedded on the installer of your application. As [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and [Xchat](http://xchat.org/) do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, libraries must be bundled with your application/installed before hand, as they are the framework upon which your application relies. If you don't install the framework, your application will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install something, not necessarily the framework. Some frameworks, like DirectX for example have a client installation. Some components are simple dll files that you can deliver with your software, creating an installation package.

Comment: is it possible for me to code without rely on any framework or library??Sorry i know my question sounds silly.

Comment: It is entirely possible to write a program that doesn't depend on libraries, yes. It's far easier, though, to use libraries that can be statically linked than it is to write all of the same code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when using a framework there will be a framework redistributable (.NET, DirectX, etc) which can be bootstrapped into your installation to install the framework (or run by the end user as the first part of "installing" your app).

Many libraries simply need to be included with your code to function correctly, they themselves might have dependencies which need to be installed but these should be called out.

If in doubt, before you distribute your package run it on a fresh install of your target system (Linux, Windows, etc) and see if it complains about missing dependencies. Include those in your package and try again.

You can also look at installation systems (RPM, Apt, Windows Installer, etc) which can handle all of these tasks for you directly (or provide scripting languages to help you automate the job).